# Draw open closing tag if value is true in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a form, which iterates over some fields.

I want to wrap some fields in a container, so that I can split the form into sections.

I have tried to put `field_open = true` under the item I want to start opening the div, and then `field_close = true` under the last field in that container and then I repeat this process.

```
<form name="{{form.form_name}}" id="{{form.form_id}}">
    <div ng-if="field.field_open == true" class="halfCol">
    <div ng-repeat="field in form.form_fields">
        <div class="{{field.field_class}}">
            <field-directive field="field"></field-directive>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div ng-if="field.field_close == true">
</form>
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I'm wondering how I can achieve this?

The below HTML is how it should be rendered:

```
<form name="test" id="test">
    <div class="halfCol">
        <label for="apple">Apple</label>
        <input type="text" name="apple" id="apple" />
        <label for="fruit">Fruit</label>
        <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" />
    </div>
    <div class="halfCol">
        <label for="dog">Dog</label>
        <input type="text" name="dog" id="dog" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The above html should be drawn from the following data.

```
var data = {
  "form_name": "test",
  "form_fields": [
    {
      "field_title": "Apple",
      "field_open" : false
      "field_open" : true
    }{
      "field_title": "Fruit",
    },{
      "field_title": "Dog",
      "field_close" : true
      "field_open" : true
    }
]}
```

I'm more or less looking for a way to wrap certain elements in the same field scope.

Comment: Dom elements exits as "nodes", and angular acts upon them as such. ng-if affects the entire node, eg the div tag an all it holds. It's explicitly incorrect html to have attributes on a close tag, it will just get peeled off by any browser. Can you explain why you'd want to have the div close tag independent of whether the open is shown?

Comment: Hi @DylanWatt I've added an example and what I'm after, I know it's invalid HTML the way I've written but I'm trying to get angular to correct this.

Comment: You can't use ng-if /ng-show /ng-hide to move things around the DOM tree. It's also not great to be declaring view logic like that in your data model, presentation is the role of the view in MVC. What leads you to placing dog in another column? I ask because the solution may be `ng-switch`ing between different well know view patterns, or it might be css based.

Comment: take a look at how `angular formly` does all of this...with a lot more config options as well. You might want to use it or just learn from the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will the decision to separete the fields in sections depend on?
If the decision depends on some aspect of presentation, I think you don't need to use model data as you do. I mean you could write simple html without ng-repeat directives.

If you insist to use model data, your model structure will be like below.

```
var data = {
    "form_name": "test",
    "form_sectinons": [
        {
            "section_title": "section 1",
            "fields": [
                {"field_title": "Apple"},
                {"field_title": "Fruit"},
            ]
        },
        {
            "section_title": "section 2",
            "fields": [
                {"field_title": "Dog"},
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And Html will be like below.

```
<form>
    <div ng-repeat="section in data.form_sections">
        <div ng-repeat="field in section.fields" class="halfCol">
            <field-directive field="field"></field-directive>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Something as simple as splitting the json object into separate array's is the correct answer here, I didn't even think of it so thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you are trying to do but you should do like this:

```
<form name="{{form.form_name}}" id="{{form.form_id}}">
    <div ng-if="field.field_open == true && field.field_close == true" class="halfCol">
        <div ng-repeat="field in form.form_fields">
            <div class="{{field.field_class}}">
                 <field-directive field="field"></field-directive>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see my example I posted, I'm after a wrapper function, not for every single field in the repeat, but only for some